# AAD Connect "Soft match issue"

Tags: active-directory, synchronization, activesync, entra-id

I upgraded to AAD Connect from sync recently before I performed a virtualization of our server infrastructure at the school I work at. I'd like to be able to move the role from my physical black box that used to do windows deployment to a few virtual machines to avoid having a single point of failure but I've been having some issues.

While the old deployment server is still syncing perfectly, the new sync server refuses to sync, claiming that there's an Invalid Softmatch. I'm getting error 0x8023134a and the detailed info I've been getting(for every single account I have on premises) goes like this:

> Unable to update this object because the following attributes associated with this object have values that may already be associated with another object in your local directory services: [ProxyAddresses SMTP:example@contoso.com;Mail example@contoso.com;].  Correct or remove the duplicate values in your local directory.  Please refer to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2647098 for more information on identifying objects with duplicate attribute values.
>
> Tracking Id: 7c9023f4-449e-4598-8f0b-1528c561364d

All the accounts are there in both AAD and ADDS, they've been working perfectly, and again the service works perfectly on my former deployment server. I can't imagine MS would code something that can't exist across multiple instances.

This is happening with every account, I saw that microsoft is saying to do a hard match or to delete and readd every account(the second just isn't going to happen), but those don't seem like real solutions. Is there a decent automated way to fix this that anyone's run into.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is by design, you cannot simultaneously run two sync engines with the same source/target. AADconnect allows you to pre-stage a single sync engine and have it configured in cold/warm standby using "Staging mode" http://blog.kloud.com.au/2015/06/25/azure-active-directory-connect-high-availability-using-staging-mode/

You will need to complete your migration to AADConnect using the correct process - follow the steps here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-aadconnect-dirsync-upgrade-get-started/

Good Luck,

Shane

Comment: There is a more formal migration process for DirSync > AAD Connect.  What OP describes is a half-done cutover.